# Identify Peugot from France, 1975-1980

Tags: identify-this-bike

I just bought a Peugeot from southern France. I guess it from 1975-1980. Can anyone help me identify it? Are there any scans from the original catalog available online?

[image: White Peugeot ca 1975][image: Badge][image: Seat post]

Comment: Great pics, that bike is a beauty!

Comment: It's clearly a bike from that era, and the components look to be original.  The rear pump peg is a curiosity, as I don't find any images online with that feature.  And I don't see a front peg -- did it get broken off?  Anyway, that may help narrow in a bit more on the specific model -- possibly a more serious touring model.

Comment: Thanks! I have really been searching and I cannot find any matching quite right. There is a pump peg on the top tube just below the bars.

Answer (score 5):

It seems to be a mid-1970s Peugeot UO8 (@mark in the comments note it may be a same-period AO8) to my eyes, essentially the male version of the 1975 mixte UO18 that I own. All of the components are identical to what I have including the MAFAC brakes and the decals.  A google image search confirms:

[image: Peugeot UO8]

A good reference website for the UO8/AO8:

http://www.mytenspeeds.com/My_TenSpeeds_1/Feature_Bicycles/Feature_Bicycles_France/Peugeot_UO8%20_BlueDump/PEUGEOT_UO8_DUMP_1_Start.htm

[image: Peugeot UO8]

Note that if that's the original AVA stem, you should immediately replace it. Google "AVA Peugeot Death Stem" if you want to know why (basically, it has a tendency to er... snap ... while riding).

Comment: Thanks! It could be an uo8 but from what I see all forks have a chrome part at the end. Mine is white. Or could that differ?

Comment: the A08 had painted forks, the U08 were chrome.

Answer (score 3):

There are some Peugeot catalogues (mostly in English, some French) from around that era at the [Veteran cycle club online library](http://veterancycleclublibrary.org.uk/library/index.php?action=search&searchtext=peugeot&items=64) (note they're not in order, but the '76, '78 and '79 catalogues are there).

Other sites include [Cycles Rétro-Peugeot](http://www.peugeotshow.com/) (various languages but I didn't see any English, decent resolution and coverage) and [BikeBoomPeugeot](http://www.bikeboompeugeot.com/Brochures%20France/Brochures_France.htm) (French, low resolution).

Your date range seems very reasonable; it's not quite right for a '76--'78 Amateur Champion (decals on forks and downtube don't match) but there's a lot that's similar.  You'll have to be careful of non-original components - obviously the bar tape is modern and it's bound to have got through a few drivetrain components in that time.

Comment: Thanks! I have been looking but I cannot find any that matches totally. Strange?

Comment: I wonder if there were colour options or paint jobs that aren't listed, combined with parts being replaced.

Comment: Exactly. Maybe even the fork has been replaced...